# Performing calculations on binned counts in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataset stored in a text file in the format of bins of values followed by counts, like this:

```
var_a 1:5 5:12 7:9 9:14 ...
```

indicating that var_a took on the value 1 5 times in the dataset, 5 12 times, etc. Each variable is on its own line in that format.

I'd like to be able to perform calculations on this dataset in R, like quantiles, variance, and so on. Is there an easy way to load the data from the file and calculate these statistics? Ultimately I'd like to make a box-and-whisker plot for each variable.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `readLines` to read in the data file

```
.x <- readLines(datafile)
```

I will create some dummy data, as I don't have the file. This should be the equivalent of the output of `readLines`

```
## dummy
.x <- c("var_a 1:5 5:12 7:9 9:14", 'var_b 1:5 2:12 3:9 4:14')
```

I split by spacing to get each

```
#split by space

space_split <- strsplit(.x, ' ')
# get the variable names (first in each list)
variable_names <- lapply(space_split,'[[',1)

# get the variable contents (everything but the first element in each list)
variable_contents <- lapply(space_split,'[',-1)

# a function to do the appropriate replicates
do_rep <- function(x){rep.int(x[1],x[2])}

# recreate the variables 

variables <- lapply(variable_contents, function(x){
  .list <- strsplit(x, ':')
  unlist(lapply(lapply(.list, as.numeric), do_rep))
})

names(variables) <- variable_names
```

you could get the variance for each variable using

```
lapply(variables, var)

## $var_a
## [1] 6.848718
## 
## $var_b
## [1] 1.138462
```

or get boxplots

```
boxplot(variables, ~.)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for going to the trouble to show the OP what to do with the data once it's in a list. I guess I had taken it for granted that they would know what to do with that. I took a different approach, mostly because I didn't want to have to create intermediate objects; however, the use of the intermediate objects does provide a certain measure of "security" in the sense that it is easier to go a couple of steps backwards if something didn't work out quite right.

Comment: Great answer. This is my first time using R, so the detail was incredibly helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Not knowing the actual form that your data is in, I would probably use something like `readLines` to get each line in as a vector, then do something like the following:

```
# Some sample data
temp = c("var_a 1:5 5:12 7:9 9:14",
         "var_b 1:7 4:9 3:11 2:10",
         "var_c 2:5 5:14 6:6 3:14")
# Extract the names
NAMES = gsub("[0-9: ]", "", temp)
# Extract the data
temp_1 = strsplit(temp, " |:")
temp_1 = lapply(temp_1, function(x) as.numeric(x[-1]))
# "Expand" the data
temp_1 = lapply(1:length(temp_1), 
                function(x) rep(temp_1[[x]][seq(1, length(temp_1[[x]]), by=2)],
                                temp_1[[x]][seq(2, length(temp_1[[x]]), by=2)]))
names(temp_1) = NAMES
temp_1
# $var_a
#  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
# 
# $var_b
#  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
# 
# $var_c
#  [1] 2 2 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```